# colorWithPatternImage and setCornerRadius issue

Tags: iphone, objective-c, rounded-corners

Hello I'd like to achieve at the same time rounded corners and a background composed by tiling a little png (`OPERATOR_VIEW_BACKGROUND_IMAGE`). My main goal is to allow a designer to fill the background of a View by inserting the right image in the project resources.

```
[triggerView setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, ICONS_WIDTH, iconFrameHeight)];
[triggerView.layer setCornerRadius:borderRadius];
[triggerView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:OPERATOR_VIEW_BACKGROUND_IMAGE]]];;
```

I don't know why but `triggerView` loose the `CornerRadius` setting when I add the last line.
`triggerView` is a `UIView` built with interface builder and modified in its `superView viewDidLoad` programmatically, with the code above.

Where I'm wrong?

EDIT: I haven't mentioned that If I use a simple `UIColor` like: `[UIColor orangeColor]` It works well. So It's something related to the `patternImage` thing.

EDIT: I've tried also this code, working on the layer background of my view:

```
[triggerView setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, ICONS_WIDTH, iconFrameHeight)];
triggerView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
UIImage *img = [UIImage imageNamed:OPERATOR_VIEW_BACKGROUND_IMAGE];
triggerView.layer.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:img].CGColor;
triggerView.layer.cornerRadius = radius;
[img release];
[self.view addSubview:triggerView];
```

Now I get a transparent background but the corners are rounded;

Comment: Have you tried switching the last 2 statements?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try setting the content property of the layer with the CGImageRef of the image:

```
triggerView.layer.contents = (id) [[UIImage imageNamed:OPERATOR_VIEW_BACKGROUND_IMAGE] CGImage];
```

You may have to alloc or retain the UIImage to prevent it being autoreleased...

Comment: No it doesn't work. BTW you need to delete the square bracket at the beginning.

Comment: Oops thanks for the fix!  This does work for me when I create a layer, set its corner radius then set its background color to clear and its masksToBounds property to yes.  I then create ANOTHER layer with the image as its contents and add this as a sublayer to achieve the effect.

Answer (score 4):

OK, thanks to Ben's comment and this [Blog entry](http://www.cimgf.com/2010/01/28/fun-with-uibuttons-and-core-animation-layers/) I've found this solution:

```
 [triggerView setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, ICONS_WIDTH, iconFrameHeight)];
 triggerView.layer.masksToBounds = YES;
 triggerView.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:OPERATOR_VIEW_BACKGROUND_IMAGE]];
 triggerView.layer.cornerRadius = radius;
 [self.view addSubview:triggerView];
```

Seems that `triggerView.layer.masksToBounds = YES;` was the missing piece, but I still don't understand `why triggerView.layer.cornerRadius = radius;` alone didn't suffice.

Answer (score 1):

With iOS SDK 4.0 and 4.1, `colorWithPatternImage` method has got a bug that show badly an image...
I used this method and I had this bug but I could resolve using another method...
Try to use the `initWithPatternImage` method of `UIColor` class:

```
UIColor *imageBg = [[UIColor alloc] initWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:OPERATOR_VIEW_BACKGROUND_IMAGE]];
```

This worked greatly for me...

Unfortunately I never used `cornerRadius` method and I don't know a possibly solution for this other problem.

Comment: I've used initWithPatternImage before colorWithPatternImage, It doesn't work and I prefer the latter to avoid adding another object to release with alloc. Anyway THX.

Comment: Thx Matthew, I had a problem with UIBezierPath and colorWithPatternImage. Using initWithPatternImage, solve the problem.